# Stars and bars with inequality and bounds (both upper and lower) on variables

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of solutions $(x,y)$ satisfying : $x,y>0$ and $x+y<41$

We find that $x,y \in \left[ 1, 40 \right]$

For the case of $x+y<41$, I substitute $x_2 = 40-x$ and $y_2 =40-y$ , this transforms the equation to:
$$ 39 \leq x_2+y_2$$

Now, the domains $x_2,y_2 \in \left[0, 39 \right]$.. now how do I count the integer solutions of the above equation?

I would know how to do it if it were $x_2 + y_2 \leq 39$, I'd introduce a new variable $k$ $x_2 + y_2 + k \leq 39$ then count the solutions to the new equation in $k$.. how do I change this method addition of new variable method to be applicable here? If it's not applicable, then how else could I solve this?

Comment: Are you looking for ordered pairs ?

Comment: Unordered @SathvikAcharya

Comment: @Buraian  The pairs must be ordered.

Comment: Why do you say that is neccesary? @N.F.Taussig

Comment: The notation $(x, y)$ means the ordered pair with $x$ as the first entry and $y$ as the second entry.  Also, the method you are using only applies to equations in which the variables are ordered.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, I thought it mean y>x or something.

Comment: Would you like to see a method of solution not based on your attempt?

Comment: I always appreciate such answers and upvote alternate methods , accepting the answer for me depends on whether I understand what the answerer is saying completely or not @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another variable works.

$x+y \lt 41; \ x, y \gt 0$

So, $x_2+y_2 \leq 38$. Number of solutions to this is same as number of solutions to,

$x_2+y_2+z = 38; \ x_2, y_2, z \geq 0$

That is given by $ \displaystyle{38 + 3 - 1 \choose 3-1} = 780$

Comment: Wait did I make mistake, how did you get less than sign and 38?

Comment: The question says $x+y \lt 41 \ $ i.e. $ \ x+y \leq 40$. Now as $x$ and $y$ are at least $1$ each, I make it $x_2 + y_2 \leq 38$.

Comment: Oh hahahaha that was too simple, it didn't occur for me to manipulate it such that it fits the lower bound. Hmm but I wonder , given an upper bound equation how would you convert it into a lower bound one?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to the problem.

We want the number of solutions to the inequality
$$x + y < 41$$
in the positive integers.  Let
$$s = 41 - (x + y)$$
Then $s$ is a positive integer and
$$x + y + s = 41$$
is an equation in the positive integers with the same number of solutions as the inequality $x + y < 41$.

The number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = x_n$$
in the positive integers is given by the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one)
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$

In this case, $n = 41$ and $k = 3$, so we obtain
$$\binom{41 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{40}{2} = 780$$
solutions to the equation $x + y + s = 41$ in the positive integers or, equivalently, to the inequality $x + y < 41$ in the positive integers.

Comment: Excellent observation